# Looking for correlation between length and angle

Tags: geometry, angle

The problem I'm facing might be rather easy to solve, but I can't think of a way how to do it atm. I want to clip straight 90-degree and some other degree lines. If I clip them at a fixed height (like h in the graphic) the 90-degree lines are too long. 
So all I need to know is how to calculate the difference (x) which occurs if the line is not rotated by angle alpha.

Variables I know: alpha and h

[image: sketch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portion of the blue line segment between the vertex and the intersection with the dashed line must have length $x+h$, and that allows you to find $x$ like so:
$$\begin{align}
\cos(\alpha)&=\frac{h}{x+h} \\[0.2ex]
x+h&=h\sec(\alpha) \\[0.7ex]
x&=h(\sec(\alpha)-1)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use Cosine(x) = adjacent / hypotenuse